# What would be more accessible : Un-ordered lists or tables?

Tags: accessibility, html5

I have a page listing the latest blog posts in a pretty standard format, you'd expect to see on any typical blog. At the foot of each post, I have a list showing 'views', 'comments' and 'shares'.

I have marked these up with `UL` and `LI` elements respectively. It's all great, but I am wondering if it could be improved / be more suited to a table; seeing as this could be seen as 'tabular data' and I am basically concerned with **best practices here, especially with regards to accessibility and screen readers.**

**My current markup:**

```
<ul class="post-stats">
<li><strong>28</strong> <small>Comments</small></li>
<li><strong>31</strong> <small>Views</small></li>
<li><strong>6</strong> <small>Shares</small></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: We can't help you with actual markup, UX is technology agnostic. However we can give advice about *what* you should be doing. What does it actually look like currently on the front end (i.e. do you have a mockup?) What exactly is the problem with the way you have done it? What are you trying to convey?

Comment: @JonW I just re-read his question and I think it belongs here since it deals with accessibility which is indeed part of user experience.

Comment: Yea, while UX is technology agnostic, it's very much tied to technology and, on the web, markup.

Comment: I think the markup you have is fine. The only adjustment I would make is to use something other than `strong` and `small` for the (presumably) font styling (use `span` for instance). `strong` and `small` will give voice inflection that isn't desirable here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend going with a list approach since as per your current code you are just providing the content in a linear order which can be read by a screen reader without issues. However if you did use Lists for indenting then, accessibility would become an issue as highlighted from the [W3C guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#lists)

> The HTML list elements DL, UL, and OL should only be used to create
>   lists, not for formatting effects such as indentation.

With regards to using tables, though [tables can be made accessible](http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data), You will need to follow some specific guidelines as highlighted below from [this article on UX Movement](http://uxmovement.com/content/useful-techniques-for-user-friendly-tables/) :

> Most tables are difficult for users to read. But they’re even more
>   difficult for disabled users to read if they’re not screen reader
>   accessible. When you make your tables accessible, disabled users will
>   get the table information read to them in a proper, understandable
>   order. Start your tables off with the summary attribute and 
>   tag. These elements give users an overview of the table contents. The
>   summary attribute gives users a broad description of the table, and
>   the caption tag gives users the title of the table. They’re the first
>   thing that comes after the table tag. Designate your row and column
>   headers using tags and data cells using tags. After that, you’ll need
>   to associate the cells with the right headers. Use the scope attribute
>   for this. The scope attribute tells the screen reader that everything
>   under a column relates to the header at the top, and everything to the
>   right of a row header relates to that header.
>
> [image]

Since I dont see any scope of perhaps adding a summary tag or header attributes, you are better off using lists.

Comment: What he has there is a list, whether the styling indents them or not is irrelevant. The W3 note you reference is talking about using list markup for something that doesn't fit a list semantically purely to provide the indentation that lists get by default.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say in general:

- Go with a simple unordered list when you only list single-dimensioned or unstructured entities.
- Go with a description list when you have structured name-value pairs for one entity.
- Go with a table when you list several structured entities that could be compared.

I guess the **description list** makes the most sense here, as the relation between label and value is explicitly given (instead of an unordered list) and you only list one entity and not the statistics of all posts (so a table would be overkill).

In HTML5, it should be done with the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) (with `dt` and `dd`). Your example would look like:

```
<dl class="post-stats">
  <dt>Comments</dt>
    <dd>28</dd>
  <dt>Views</dt>
    <dd>31</dd>
  <dt>Shares</dt>
    <dd>6</dd>
</dl>
```

Thanks to that markup, user-agents (like screenreaders) could know that "Comments" is the term/name and "28" its corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

Basic question you should ask yourself: do you need rows and columns? Do you need some kind of cross-referencing and/or sortable on different properties of the individual items? In that case, use a table. Otherwise, use an unordered (or ordered) list.